# Confusing about a function :before_filter

Tags: ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1, before-filter

I have following controller:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :user, :name
  before_filter :require_user, :except => [:my_action]

  def index
  end

  ...

  def my_action
  end
end
```

I want to allow to see all actions in this controller only for log in users - this works me fine. But the action `my_action` I would like to have accesible for everyone - also for a people who are not log in.

I tried to set `:before_filter` with the `:except` parameter, also with the `:only` parameter, but nothing works me... The app always want for me to be log in... what I am doing still wrong?

**EDIT**: `require_user` from application_controller.rb:

```
   def require_no_user
      logger.debug "ApplicationController::require_no_user"
      if current_user
        #store_location
        flash[:warning] = "You must be logged out to access this page"
        redirect_to account_url
        return false
      end
    end
```

Comment: What is that `require_user`? Where it came from?

Comment: Maybe this was just a typo ... but `dev my_action` should be `def my_action` ... is that how it's typed in your actual code?

Comment: Also, do you have the filter in your application controller? If so, you need to skip it in this controller.

Comment: @JustinM - of course, in my code is `def`, not `dev`, it's a fault that I made when I typed this message.

Comment: As your method is written now, it returns `false` if there's a `current_user` ... is that what you intend?

Comment: Solved with using `skip_before_filter`.

Comment: If you're using a new version of rails, it should be `skip_filter`

Answer (score 1):

Use 
skip_before_filter :require_user, :only => [:my_action]